# Keep getting Issues on handling multiple records-List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex

I'm trying to modify my code which works for single account, but I need to handle multiple accounts.

```
split[0] : holds the account name
split[1] : holds the email
```

This is my code:

```
list<string> slistAcc = new list<string>{'abc_rt@gm.com','fd_io@ui.com'};
system.debug(slistAcc);

list<account> acct = new list<account>();
list<account> p2 = new list<account>();

string[] b;

for(integer i=0;i<slistAcc.size();i++) 
{


    string a = slistAcc[i];
      b = a.split('_');

    system.debug('b --->' + b); << ---DEBUG|b --->(abc, rt@gm.com)

    if(!b.IsEmpty())
    {
        acct[i].name = b[0];  <<---keeps failing in this assignment. 

     acct[i].email = b[1];
    system.debug('acct' + acct[i]);    
       p2.add(acct[i])  <--------- 
    }


}
insert p2;
```

The code keeps failing at the assignment to `**acct[i].name = b[0]**` saying `List index out of bounds...` . I don't get how can I assign multiple accounts to a variable. or a list to a list [b is also a list and acct is also a list]. What am trying to achieve is from the split list get account name and email assign  to new list -- this needs to be looped through several data in that split array. Now capture all these new assigned values and insert in system using p2.
Please advise. Also please excuse me as I'm still getting used to Apex.

Comment: updated my code as below to get rid of list bounded error : but doesnt give me the result as required:                                                                                                |DEBUG|b --->(abc, rt@gm.com)                                                                                           |DEBUG|b --->(fd, io@ui.com)                                                                                |DEBUG|(Account:{Name=fd}, Account:{Name=fd})  <---this is incorrect-wanted to contain both abc and fd.     How shall i take care of the assignment?

Comment: Sorted found the issue!!   within the for loop has to initialise the account rather than keeping it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string [] email= new string[]{'ram-m@gmail.com','mahi-m@gmail.com'};

    list<account> a= new list<account>();

for(integer i=0;i<email.size();i++)
    {
        account acc= new account();

        acc.name=email[i].split('-')[0];
        acc.email__c=email[i];
        a.add(acc);
    }

insert a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list instantiation does not appear to be correct, as you need parentheses. The type you are using is also incorrect, as it is `Account`, not `Accounts`. Unless you have some custom class called `accounts`?

```
List<Account> p = new List<Account>();
```

As for the index error, you will not get any errors if you iterate through the elements like so:

```
for (Account acct : accountList)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

It won't do anything with an empty list, but you need to populate it somehow and that is outside the scope of your question.

Also, there is no `sObject` method called `split` so it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish there.

Comment: Thanks Adrian!! minelogic  has to go with the split. Have updated my query explaining why am using split.

Answer (score 1):

It does have several errors in your code. You use the p[i] before the p list still have no any elements, that's why you got the "index out of bounds" error.
I did some change for your code, hope to help you:

```
List<String> emails = {'abc__ab@gm.com','cdf__fg@ui.com'};
List<account> p = new list<account>;

for (i=0;i < emails.size();i++)
{
    Account acct = new Account();
    acct.name = emails[i].split('__')[0]
    acct.email = emails[i];
    p.add(acct);
}

insert p;
```

Comment: I believe the array has name__email values. so split[0] is name and split[1] is email. can you update your code accordingly.

Comment: In the code, we got the array by spliting email. so split[0] is name and split[1] is just domain, not email.

Comment: Thanks Allen, but am looking for the details as Vamsi Mentioned.